# QProxyModel which will expose a Subtree only

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I need to expose a part of a tree model as a new tree model.

So given a tree model like this:

```
- a
 |- b
   |- c
- d
 |- e
```

i want to specify a root element, e.g. `a` which will yield a new model with the following structure

```
- b
 |- c
```

without actually copying the data.

Therefore I was thinking that a proxy model is a natural fit for that. I'm aware that in my View classes I can set the RootIndex as desired. However I have a different use case, I want to use the part of the tree as a completion model for a `QCompleter`.

I started by subclassing `QAbstractProxyModel`.

```
class SubTreeModel : public QAbstractProxyModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SubTreeModel(QObject* parent = nullptr);

public:

    QModelIndex RootIndex() const;
    void SetRootIndex(QModelIndex rootIndex);
    QModelIndex mapToSource(const QModelIndex &proxyIndex) const override;
    QModelIndex mapFromSource(const QModelIndex &sourceIndex) const override;
QModelIndex index(int row, int column, const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    QModelIndex parent(const QModelIndex &child) const override;
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const override;

private:
    QModelIndex m_rootIndex;
};
```

The `m_rootIndex` then should be an index into the source model, which acts as the root of the Proxy model.

In my understanding the most important thing is to get `mapToSource` and `mapFromSource` right and then just use them in the remaining functions. However I'm facing difficulties, this is what I came up with so far e.g. for `mapToSource`:

```
QModelIndex SubTreeModel::mapToSource(const QModelIndex& proxyIndex) const
{
    if (not sourceModel() or not m_rootIndex.isValid() or not proxyIndex.isValid())
    {
        return QModelIndex();
    }

    /* accessing the root element of the proxy must be redirected to the correct root element in the
     * whole tree */
    if (not proxyIndex.parent().isValid())
    {
        return sourceModel()->index(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(), m_rootIndex);
    }
    return sourceModel()->createIndex(proxyIndex.row(), proxyIndex.column(),
                                      proxyIndex.parent().internalPointer());
}
```

The last `return` does not compile since `createIndex` is a protected member.
In the implementation of e.g. `QSortFilterProxyModel` or `QIdentityProxyModel` they are able to call the `createIndex` function of the source model, by using D-Pointer tricks. Do i need to do the same (this feels insane!). Is there another way of solving this, which is more elegant? Or can it be done without using the `createIndex` function?

Comment: You say *I need to expose a part of a tree model as a new tree model*, and I wonder what part do you want to show? Also, in which view do you want to show that part of the tree?

Comment: so when the tree is something like this:
- a
 |- b
   |- c
 |- d
   | - e

i want a proxy with e.g. the root element `b` such that the proxy tree looks only like this:
- b
   |- c

i do not need the subtree for a particular view, instead i wanted to use it as a completion model in a `QCompleter`.

Comment: ok now new lines, original tree `{a:{b:{c}, d:{e}}}`, subtree with `b` as new root: `{b:{c}}`

Comment: Note: the format of the comments does not allow you to understand what you want, besides that it is the most important information since it indicates your underlying objective, so it is recommended that you place it in the post